# How do I make a ban, kick and clear command for my bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to know how to make a ban, kick and clear commands for my bot. I will show you the code but before that I have been doing reasearch and nothing been working. I use node.js and i am a beginner so here's what i need you to tell me.

-The code for the command (No external links)
-How to to get the code to work.
-Where to put the code.

Okay, heres the code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '!help') {
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Ratchet Commands")
.setDescription("!getpizza, !shutup, !playdead, !server-info, !myname, !banhammer, !yourcreator, !annoy, !youare")
.setColor("RANDOM")
message.channel.send(embed)
}
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!getpizza') {
        message.channel.send('Welcome to Ratchets Pizza!!! Heres your pizza and have a nice day!!! :pizza:');
    }
});


bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!shutup') {
        message.channel.send('Okay, I am sorry.');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!server-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!myname') {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}`);
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!rocket') {
        message.channel.send('3..2..1..Blast Off!!! :rocket:');
    }
});

bot.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '!youare') {
        message.channel.send(`I am <@!808773656700256318>`);
    }
});
bot.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '!yourcreator') {
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Ratchets Creator")
.setDescription("My creator is <@!765607070539579402>")
.setColor("RANDOM")
message.channel.send(embed)
}
});


bot.on('message', message => {
if(message.content.startsWith(`!annoy`)) {
    const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!mentionedUser) return message.channel.send("You have to mention someone to continue annoying someone :rofl:");
    mentionedUser.send('You have a problem with me?');
    message.channel.send("Annoyed " + mentionedUser + "! (Oh wait, I annoyed them 2 times!)");
}
});


module.exports = {
    name: '!kick',
    description: "this command kicks people",
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.member(member);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("bing bong he is gone!");
        }else{
            message.channel.send('you couldnt kick that person');
        }
    }
}

bot.login('TOKEN');
```

I know I need a command handler but I don't know how to do that neither.

Thank you!!!

Comment: "*I use node.js and i am a beginner*" While outside the scope of your question as you've posed it, you should probably consider tacking some lower-complexity tasks to learn the fundamentals of the language you're working with before graduating to something as complex as a Discord bot. Here on Stack Overflow, we focus on singular, specific, answerable coding problems. Your question is *way* too broad for Stack Overflow's Q&A format (likely in part or entirely due to your lack of fundamental knowledge in the language you're using) - see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You can also learn the basics from https://discordjs.guide/ and [learn how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions on Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you did a very big error, you always recall the `message` event, optimize your code like this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

bot.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

bot.on('message', message => {
if(message.content === '!help') {
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Ratchet Commands")
.setDescription("!getpizza, !shutup, !playdead, !server-info, !myname, !banhammer, !yourcreator, !annoy, !youare")
.setColor("RANDOM")
message.channel.send(embed)

if (message.content === '!getpizza') {
        message.channel.send('Welcome to Ratchets Pizza!!! Heres your pizza and have a nice day!!! :pizza:');
}

if (message.content === '!server-info') {
        message.channel.send(`Server name: ${message.guild.name}\nTotal members: ${message.guild.memberCount}`);
    }

if (message.content === '!myname') {
        message.channel.send(`Your username: ${message.author.username}`);
    }

if (message.content === '!rocket') {
        message.channel.send('3..2..1..Blast Off!!! :rocket:');
    }

if (message.content === '!youare') {
        message.channel.send(`I am <@!808773656700256318>`);
    }

if(message.content === '!yourcreator') {
let embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle("Ratchets Creator")
.setDescription("My creator is <@!765607070539579402>")
.setColor("RANDOM")
message.channel.send(embed)
}

if(message.content.startsWith(`!annoy`)) {
    const mentionedUser = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!mentionedUser) return message.channel.send("You have to mention someone to continue annoying someone :rofl:");
    mentionedUser.send('You have a problem with me?');
    message.channel.send("Annoyed " + mentionedUser + "! (Oh wait, I annoyed them 2 times!)");
}

});

module.exports = {
    name: '!kick',
    description: "this command kicks people",
    execute(message, args){
        const member = message.mentions.users.first();
        if(member){
            const memberTarget = message.guild.member(member);
            memberTarget.kick();
            message.channel.send("bing bong he is gone!");
        }else{
            message.channel.send('you couldnt kick that person');
        }
    }
}

bot.login('TOKEN');
```

then to do a !ban @mention  you can do:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!ban ')) {
                if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
                    if (!message.mentions.members.first().bannable) {
                        message.channel.send('I can\'t ban the specified user')
                        return
                    }
                    try {
                        message.mentions.members.first().ban()
                    }finally {
                        message.channel.send('The member was correctly banned')
                    }
                }
            }
```

and for a !kick

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!kick ')) {
                if (message.mentions.members.first()) {
                    if (!message.mentions.members.first().kickable) {
                        message.channel.send('I can\'t kick the specified user')
                        return
                    }
                    try {
                        message.mentions.members.first().kick
                    }finally {
                        message.channel.send('The member was correctly kicked')
                    }
                }
            }
```

and finally for the clear command

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!clear ')) {
                let toClear = args[1]
                for (let i = 0; i < toClear; i++) {
                    m.channel.lastMessage.delete()
                }
            }
```

Hope i helped you ^^